# Dart, null reference exception on static member

Tags: dart

I have the following class:

```
class Label{

  static PopOver contextMenu; // can I put = new PopOver(); here?

  Label(){
    if(Label.contextMenu == null){ //null reference exception here why????
      Label.contextMenu = new PopOver();
    }
  }

}
```

but I am getting a null reference exception on the `Label.contextMenu` should I be getting a null reference exception when I'm checking for null? and also can you initialise static members inline where you declare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not get a null reference exception with this code. I have tested it and I do not get any error.

You definitely can initialize static members inline. Whether you should do so depends on the situation. If the contextMenu will never change, consider making it final as well:

```dart
static final PopOver contextMenu = new PopOver();
```

Comment: but why do I get a null reference exception when I'm doing `if(Label.contextMenu == null)` that's the bit that makes no sense to me, but thanks for the other part of the answer.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make any sense. I do not get that error when running your code so I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: ignore my last comment I just retested it and it isnt throwing any exceptions now :S maybe I mispeled `Label` perhaps. well thanks anyway